# Admob or Ad plugin for Android available for Cordova/Phonegap 3.3?

Tags: cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

I need to implement ads on an application but all of the ad plugins I have found are for earlier versions of PhoneGap. Are there any available for 3.3? If not, will the older plugins work for 3.3? (maybe with some modification?) thanks!

EDIT/SOLUTION: I posted a related question and eventually found a solution for anyone in need of help with this same issue. A detailed solution for implementing Admob in Cordova 3.3 is listed in the question under a final edit I made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647417/admob-plugins-compatible-with-phonegap-3-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plugin maintained by aliokan should work in 3.3.0 
https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob

It was updated to be compatible with PhoneGap 3.0 some 5 months ago, since then there has been no changes to the way plugins are written. So it should work fine.

However if you are wanting to submit your app to Google Play store, they are few small changes to make but nothing overly complicated as mentioned by this user https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob/issues/8

Comment: Thank you very much! Just want I was looking for.

Comment: Is the plugin 3.4.0 compatible?

Comment: hi @tipycalFlow 3.4.0 brings major changes to the File protocol. I've briefly gone over this plugin and doesn't seem to call this function. Should be compatible with 3.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

AdMob plugins compatible with PhoneGap 3.4 and cordova 3.5

https://code.google.com/p/admob-phonegap/

support ios and android

support all admob banner size

support all native event

support the last admob ios sdk and admo google play service sdk

support admob v1 and admob v2

support intel xdk

support phonegap and cordova

support online install command

cordova plugin add com.admob.AdmobPlugin

Answer (score 0):

We found a blog. There we can add admob in Phonegap android app without any plugin
Here is link of this blog

http://phonegapguru.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-add-native-admob-ad-in.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

AdMob plugins compatible with PhoneGap 3.4 and cordova 6

https://github.com/admob-google/admob-cordova

support ios and android

support all admob banner size

support all native event

support the last admob ios sdk and admo google play service sdk

support admob v1 and admob v2

support intel xdk

support phonegap and cordova

support online install command

```
cordova plugin add admob
```